# Pick specific keys and reduce with same keys

Tags: typescript, interface, key

I have a use-case where I need to generate an interface that inherits typing from another class with specific keys, and builds from there. I need to use this inherited-type, but also reduce data via JS into an instance of the inherited-type. Is there a way to only need to list off the keys once?

I am currently doing it like this:

```js
interface IPrimaryType {
  key1: string;
  key2: string;
  key3: string;
  key4: string;
  key5: string;
  key6: string;
  key7: string;
}

interface ISecondaryType {
  thisDoesntMatter: string;
}

interface ITertiaryType {
  thisDoesntMatter: string;
}

interface IInheritedType extends Pick<IPrimaryType, 'key1' | 'key2' | 'key3' | 'key4' | 'key5'> {
  secondaryData: ISecondaryType;
  tirtiaryData?: ITertiaryType | null;
}

const inheritedKeys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4', 'key5'];

const primaryObj = {
  key1: 'value1',
  key2: 'value2',
  key3: 'value3',
  key4: 'value4',
  key5: 'value5',
  key6: 'value6',
  key7: 'value7',
};
const secondaryData = { thisDoesntMatter: '' };
const tirtiaryData = { thisDoesntMatter: '' };

let inheritedObj = inheritedKeys.reduce(
  (acc, key: string) => ({ ...acc, [key]: (primaryObj as any)[key] }),
  {} as IInheritedType
);
inheritedObj.secondaryData = secondaryData;
inheritedObj.tirtiaryData = tirtiaryData;
```

Comment: Please [edit] to provide a [mre] we can paste into our own IDEs to work on this without unrelated errors (like undefined types and values).  It's possible you want [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w869Am), but with all those errors I can't tell.

Comment: Thanks @jcalz, I updated the original post. I copied your example, and it works! I swear I tried this before but must have made a mistake... [Here's the updated code in your style, feel free to add as a solution and I'll mark it.](https://tsplay.dev/w2kyzN)

Comment: Okay, I'll do so when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't derive values like `inheritedKeys` from types like `'key1' | 'key2' | 'key3' | 'key4' | 'key5'`, since the type system is [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types) upon compilation.  But you can do the reverse and derive types from values.  Like this:

```
const inheritedKeys = [
  'key1',
  'key2',
  'key3',
  'key4',
  'key5',
] as const;

type InheritedKeys = typeof inheritedKeys[number];
// type InheritedKeys = "key1" | "key2" | "key3" | "key4" | "key5"
```

You have to use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to ask the compiler to keep track of the [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the initializer of `inheritedKeys`.  Otherwise `inheritedKeys` would be of type `string[]` and the individual elements like `"key3"` would be forgotten.

Once you do that, the [`typeof` type query operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html) can be used to get the type of the `inheritedKeys` variable, and by [indexing into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) that with `number` you get the type of the values at numeric indices of `inheritedKeys`; that is, the element type.

And so `InheritedKeys` is the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of the literal types of the elements.  And you can use `InheritedKeys` inside your definition of `IInheritedType`:

```
interface IInheritedType extends Pick<IPrimaryType, InheritedKeys> {
  secondaryData: ISecondaryType;
  tertiaryData?: ITertiaryType | null;
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.6#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAUrALZygTwBV8AHFAbwChlkBrCfARgC5kBnMLEAcwG5q6DAEysOXPgPr4AzKM6gJNKQBY54-koYBWNQo2D8ANl099UgOwmJAX0phSKVCAAW0YJAAmAaQZtkAXmR7MgB7GGRQVyxPH3w2AG0QAFdsACNoAF1+AHpsoIc0FzcY3wDkACIpRnLkAB8KqSEa+sqGaWaGhmUO1vwtcspKUEhYREcAZQgEEJAPPCICqhowZ2A2ABEQiDZwAFk4MBGrflsh8Gh4JDRCaDBgeeIyZCWg1Y2tnbB9w+hjylPpiAOBEitEIN5SoF4gIAORVGEAGlhjURyLaqJocK6GOQWL6qIyyDgfkBHH4ZxGl0cTii7nBjxQEAAHpBZn50MAELQADwYLC4AgMhGFWklOIAPmeAjYUxmcwI6wOcFYqEmgPlCzI+hGd3mirAcAA-CqblBdYKCvVkgAba0nQaksDIEj8+YAeVSACsyi8qqwYQA3ODWpIQRg4xr+oMhiBCCNtKPB0PSeP4VS46Oh5SpnQZpMQLSp4x5mOGVOWEuh8yo2yO9iy2Z6pU+15rTbbPYHI64mHIaz8Os6+4K5uBcit94dr5d349vvk60QJ2RYrgj3ewIrsEQuIAOig4KSSAAFAJj4gEMKpFYAJQBSXH8e758X4XxKQZVjHl04d1eol+HAID4De74MIS1g3kiNDkNYAFoDSq4eAylA3vwW50h4667jK6pNgaZS4XK+FwOhoKYdhQ4kWUVEjgavBAA)